# How fetch data to a @Published array with a completion from Core Data within a performBackgroundTask block?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'd like to fetch data to a @Published array with a completion from Core Data within a performBackgroundTask block. If have to work with a lot of data, it could blocks the GUI so I want to perform database operations in the background. The GUI is written in SwiftUI.

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Shared
//
//  Created by DEV on 31/03/2021.
//

import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                contentViewModel.addItem()
            } label: {
                Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
            }
            if !contentViewModel.items.isEmpty {
                List {
                    ForEach(contentViewModel.items) { item in
                        if let tt = item.timestamp {
                            Text("Item at \(tt, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                        } else {
                            Text("No item timestamp")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let coreDataStack = PersistenceController.shared
    
    @Published var items : [Item] = []
    
    init() {
        getItems()
    }
    
    func getItems() {
        let fetchItemsCompletion : (Result<[Item], Error>) -> Void = { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let fetchedItems):
                    self.items = fetchedItems
                case .failure( _):
                    NSLog("fetchAllConsumption failure");
            }
        }
        fetchAllItemFromCoreData(completion: fetchItemsCompletion)
    }
    
    func addItem() {
        let addItemCompletion : (Result<Item, Error>) -> Void = { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let fetchedItem):
                    self.items.insert(fetchedItem, at: 0)
                case .failure( _):
                    NSLog("fetchAllConsumption failure");
            }
        }
        addItemToCoreData(completion: addItemCompletion)
    }
    
    
    func addItemToCoreData(completion: @escaping (Result<Item, Error>) -> Void) {
        coreDataStack.container.performBackgroundTask { context in  //its not working
            let newItem = Item(context: context)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
            do {
                try context.save()
                completion(.success(newItem))
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
    func fetchAllItemFromCoreData(completion: @escaping (Result<[Item], Error>) -> Void) {
        coreDataStack.container.performBackgroundTask { context in  //its not working
            do {
                let teaRequest: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
                let result = try context.fetch(teaRequest)
                completion(.success(result))
            }
            catch {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
    
}

private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()
```

If I add items, I get *[SwiftUI] Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.* error message.

In the fetch, there is no timestamp visible on the list.

It's work well if I fetch data in main thread with the viewContext of NSPersistentContainer.

I've generated a lot of data to test, here you can download:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xqhn0b4mtzumz1/FetchInBackground_sqlite.zip

After the first run in the simulator you can find the created sqlite with this command in terminal:

*find /Users/$USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices -iname FetchInBackground.sqlite*

Now you can replace it with the files found in the zip.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. Download links are unacceptable for continuity all the required code should be included in the question.

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I've deleted the download link about the source code, there is just one sqlite file, but it not necessary to test. I've wrote a full sample code that you can use.